# Show $y_1(t) = y(t)\int^t_{t_0} \frac 1 {x_1(s)^2} e^{-\int_{t_0}^s p(r) dr} ds$ solves the 2-nd order ODE: $x'' + p(t)x' + q(t)x = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $(I,y)$ solves the 2-nd order ODE: $x'' + p(t)x' + q(t)x = 0$.

Assume $y(t) \neq 0$ for $t \in I$ and let $t_o \in I$.

I want to show that $(I, y_1)$ where $$y_1(t) = y(t)\int^t_{t_0} \frac 1 {x_1(s)^2} e^{-\int_{t_0}^s p(r) dr} ds$$ is also a solution of the above ODE (it is assumed $p,q \in C^{0}(I)$, where $I$ is an interval).

How can I show $y_1(t)$ is a solution ? I've tried by direct computation, but the derivatives I get are quite messy and the sum afterwards are exhausting to compute and does not directly reflect that $y_1$ is a solution ...

Answer (score 2):

this method of reducing the order of a linear differential equation is called the variation of parameter. what you do is assume you have found one solution $y$ of 
$$x^{\prime \prime} + px^\prime + qx = 0 \tag 1$$ now you assume a solution of the form $$x = yu, x^\prime = y^\prime u + yu^\prime, 
x^{\prime \prime}= y^{\prime \prime}u+2y^\prime u^\prime +y u^{\prime \prime}$$ 
where $u$ is arbitrary now, but we will impose constraints later.

if you substitute all of the above in $(1)$ and use the fact $y$ is a solution, we end up with $$ 2y^\prime u^\prime +y u^{\prime \prime} + pyu^\prime = yu^{\prime \prime}+(2y^\prime + py)u^\prime= 0$$

this is a first order equation 
$$\dfrac{u^{\prime \prime}}{u^\prime} + 2\dfrac{y^\prime}{y} + p = 0$$ 
 for $u^\prime$ which can be integrated as
$\ln (u^\prime) + 2 \ln y+\int pdt = \ln A $ which can be rewritten in exponential form as 
$$ u^\prime = \dfrac{Ae^{-\int_{t_0}^t pdt}}{y^2}, 
u = A\int_{t_0}^t\dfrac{e^{-\int_{t_0}^s pds}}{y^2(s)} \ ds$$

Comment: How do you get that integral after you say "this is a first order equation for $u'$ ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen, i have added a line. see if that makes it easier to see.

Comment: Have you made the assumption that $u' \neq 0$ ? :)

Comment: only thing is $u$ is not a constant. we already know that $u = constant$ is a solution. that is the assumption. we are trying to find a nonconstant $u.$